# Why is my Android Studio (Kotlin) showing the layout of an Android phone in Preview but not in the Build App?

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin

I made a simple app in the Android Studio. I took two TextViews and one Button in XML layout file. Both textview and Button are showing in the preview but in the Build Apk there is only Button Showing. It doesn't giving any error. I don't know what is the problem I tried all the possible ways to fix it but didn't get anything.

*activity_home XML code*

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:hint="mnail"
              android:id="@+id/editText"/>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textViewSendEmail"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:hint="Email"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textViewSendPassword"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSendEmail"/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_width="344dp"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="send"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textViewSendPassword"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

*MainActivity code*

```
package com.kotlinintent

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_home.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)

        var email_user = textViewSendEmail.text
        var password_user = textViewSendPassword.text

        sendButton.setOnClickListener {
            intent = Intent(this, SecondActvity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("email", email_user)
            intent.putExtra("password", password_user)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

*SecondActivity*

```
package com.kotlinintent

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_second.*

class SecondActvity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second)


        var bundle : Bundle? = intent.extras
        var emailData = bundle!!.getString("email")
        var passwordData = bundle.getString("password")

        textViewEmail.text = emailData
        textViewPassword.text = passwordData
    }
}
```

*Second Activity XML*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".SecondActvity">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewEmail"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Email"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="Password"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/getButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="44dp"
            android:text="get"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: we may need more information from your logcat

Comment: share your kotlin code

Comment: Check your background color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of these lines

```
var email_user = textViewSendEmail.text
var password_user = textViewSendPassword.text
```

Use this

```
var email_user = textViewSendEmail.text.toString()
var password_user = textViewSendPassword.text.toString()
```

And also you must call these lines in onclick so your code must like this

```
 sendButton.setOnClickListener {
        var email_user = textViewSendEmail.text.toString()
        var password_user = textViewSendPassword.text.toString()
        intent = Intent(this, SecondActvity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("email", email_user)
        intent.putExtra("password", password_user)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

And i suggest that use `wrap_content` instead of static size (`44dp`) for height

Comment: @PankajTungaria did you type anything in EditTexts ?

Comment: it works.. thanks @Radesh and thanks all of you guys the problem was i made objects of textview outside of onclick method. but don't why that object matter because these textviews are static.. anyway thank you

Comment: @PankajTungaria when you call that in you get current text of EditText, so when call in onCreate() it's still null and when you call it in btn click it have some text

Answer (score 0):

Your issue in the way how you put extras. In MainActivity you put your data as extras for intent. But in SecondActivity you try to get data from intent's bundle.

Change this

```
var bundle : Bundle? = intent.extras
var emailData = bundle!!.getString("email")
var passwordData = bundle.getString("password")
```

for this

```
var emailData = intent.getStringExtra("email")
var passwordData = intent.getStringExtra("password")`
```

Or you can put data into Bundle in MainActivity, then put this Bundle into intent. And then get data, as you do with your current solution.

Comment: I tried it but nothing has changed. Exactly problem is "Xml textview not showing in build apk file i thing static layout and views always shows without making objects".

Comment: They should be visible. Try not to set text for them from activity, leave only text which you set in xml through `text` parameter.